# labeling the density legend in heatmap.2

Tags: r, heatmap

I am using `heatmap.2` from `gplots`. However, the final graph displays "Value" and "Count" for  the X and Y axis respectfully.

How can I change this ? Here is my line:

```
library(gplots)
heatmap.2(mat)
```

Answer (score 0):

It seems the only way that I have found is to define my own heatmap.3 function based on heatmap.2 and rename manually the axis for the "legend" plot.